# How does -z execstack affect the compilation and execution of a shared object (.so)

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, dynamic-linking

If the program that is loading the .so is compiled normally (not executable stack), then what would happen at run time, would this option be ignored, or will the .so's frames be executables ?

Comment: On what OS?  GNU/Linux?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, though I tried it and it seems the stack stays non executable.

Comment: That's what I guessed would happen; the initial stack mapping is created by the kernel based on metadata in the executable itself, before the dynamic linker code even looks at other metadata in the executable that has a list of dynamic library dependencies.  It's not completely impossible that the dynamic linker code could use `mprotect` to change the stack mapping, although IDK if that could affect new pages as the stack grows.  (Or set the process "personality" to READ_IMPLIES_EXEC, [the old way the kernel implemented what `-z execstack` requests](//stackoverflow.com/q/64833715/224132).)